# Knitr error in loading in-built data

Tags: r, knitr

I am trying to run a code in R using knitr compiler. It for some reason generates this error:

```
Error in str(Oats) : object 'Oats' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> str
Execution halted
```

Here is the code I am using:

````
```{r}
data(Oats)
str(Oats)
plot(Oats)
sp.oats <- within(Oats, nitroF <- factor(nitro))
model1=lm(yield~Variety*nitro,data=Oats)
summary(model1)
model2=lme(yield~Variety*nitro,data=Oats,random=~1|Block/Variety/nitro)
summary(model2)
coef(model1)
coef(model2)
plot(ranef(model2))
plot(model2)
```
````

Please suggest what I should do to resolve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the package loaded (to an environment to which knitr would have access) that has Oats?

Comment: There is no package

Comment: Where did you get the data set Oats? It certainly is not built in my version of R.

Comment: It comes with base R. Just type Oats and it's there.

Comment: Ah, that explains it @42-.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
data(Oats,package="nlme")
```

Quotation marks are optional around the data set name (`Oats`, `"Oats"`) but mandatory for the package name (`"nlme"`).

But

```
library(nlme)
data(Oats)
```

will also work, and since you're going to be using functions from `nlme` anyway, you might as well do it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Adding comment as an answer. I thought it might be a duplicate (ansd still suspect it might be, but I couldn't find it in a search, so maybe it will be useful in subsequent searches.:

It is in the `nlme`-package which is not loaded by default, but it is shipped with every copy of R since its priority is "recommended". @MAPK should add a line that says `data(Oats, pac=nlme)` before he tries to access it, and `hpesoj626` should try that at his console. Of course, that will then possibly lead to another error since the `lme`-function might not be there. So I think the final solution might be

````
```{r}
 library(nlme)
 data(Oats)` 
 ....
````

as a starting point (inside the knitted section).